# Dynamic visualization for top n values

Tags: excel

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
Date    CONSUMER DISCR    CONSUMER STAPLES    ENERGY      FINANCIALS    HEALTH CARE   INDUSTRIALS     INFORMATION TECH      MATERIALS     REAL ESTATE    TELECOM SVC    UTILITIES

2/28/2006   0.16630621      0.045185409     0.044640056   0.123505969    0.053980333    0.088535648   0.234666154        0.119729025      0.034316211   0.067272708     0.021862279
3/31/2006   0.13323423     0.0135331245     0.022255232    0.124240924   0.054290724    0.088825904    0.055432         0.118432505         0.03418562  0.066877285     0.33847323
```

Each of the numbers for the sectors indicates the importance of the industry to the stock market. I am not interested in all industries but the top n most important ones. (the higher the number, the more important the industry is).

**I want a method in Excel that dynamically visualizes the top n values for each date**. For example, for 2/28/2006, for n = 4, it should visualize`INFORMATION TECH`, `CONSUMER DISCR`, `FINANCIALS`, and `MATERIALS`.

For 3/31/2006, for n = 4, it should visualize`UTILITIES`, `CONSUMER DISCR`, `FINANCIALS`, and `MATERIALS`

What method exists in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the supplied image,

```
=INDEX($1:$1, , MATCH(LARGE($B2:$L2, COLUMN(A:A)), $A2:$L2, 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use something like this:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1) >$O$1,"",INDEX($A$1:$L$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B$1:$L$1)/(INDEX($B$2:$L$3,MATCH($O$2,$A$2:$A$3,0),0)=LARGE(INDEX($B$2:$L$3,MATCH($O$2,$A$2:$A$3,0),0),ROW(1:1))),1)))
```

You would put this in the first cell and copy down far enough to satisfy the largest n possible.

[image]